# Spring security- Attribute level security restriction in REST API

Tags: java, rest, reflection, spring-security, attributes

We are in a process of implementing REST API on top of our existing services backend. 
The controller has the following simple getter method, which returns a Json.

The controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}" , method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<IDTO> getIDTO(@PathVariable long id){
    }
```

DTO Interface

```
public interface IDTO {
    public long getId();
    public double getCost();
    public void setCost(double cost);
    public double getPrice();
    }
```

need to restrict "cost" attribute according to the user permission, in both getter and setter

I have tried with custom  `@PostAuthorize()` and `@PreAuthorize()`

Bu in this method, i have to use reflection to read each field associated with the DTO. Which might produce slower execution in large DTO s.

What is the correct way of achieving this ?